# Javascript: var myFunc = function() vs. var myFunc = function myFunc()

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these?

```
var myFunc = function() {
  // ...
};
```

vs.

```
var myFunc = function myFunc() {
  // ...
};
```

In the 2nd example, `arguments.callee.caller.name` works, but not in the first one. Is there anything wrong with the 2nd syntax?

Comment: `var func=function F(){};` will make `F()` available inside function block, but not outside.

Comment: `arguments.callee` is deprecated, so use named function expressions if you need that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` in a function literal is optional, if omitted as in the first case you show the function is said to be *anonymous*.

This is from [*JavaScript: The Good Parts* by Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/):

> A function literal has four parts.  The first part is the reserved word *function*.  The optional second part is the function's name.  The function can use its name to call itself recursively.  The name can also be used by debuggers and development tools to identify the function.  If a function is not given a name, as shown in the previous example, it is said to be *anonymous*.

Comment: You mentioned one of my favorite books; thanks. I will review this section.

Answer (score 7):

The second one has a name while the first one doesn't. Functions are objects that have a property `name`. If the function is anonymous then it has no name.

```
var a = function(){}; // anonymous function expression
a.name; //= empty

var a = function foo(){}; // named function expression
a.name; //= foo
```

Comment: What are the pros and cons of each?  Is there anything wrong with the 2nd syntax?

Comment: (Other than duplicity of naming)

Comment: There's no duplicity. The first one doesn't have a name. The advantage is that you can call the function within the function for recursion, and that you can see the name in the call stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

The first function doesn't *have* a name.

Assigning a function to a variable doesn't give the function a name.